# Can I use VS2010 ENG if I got otherlang Lincense?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, licensing, license-key

I got license for Visual Studio 2010 professional 2010 - Russian

So can I use English version ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Licensing is not tied to languages, but rather to the installation media (or, on an OEM version, the hardware). You can use a Russian license key with an English CD/DVD, as long as your license key is not currently in use with another computer. You must remove any existing installations on other machines in order to comply with the EULA.

(I can't find any particular link at the moment confirming this, so if you're really worried about it, you should contact Microsoft support for verification. I am not qualified to provide legal advice, blah blah blah. Otherwise, this is pretty clearly legit; I personally wouldn't worry about it.)